# Build a initializer with Rxjs

Tags: rxjs

I have two promises that need to execute in order. After they successfully finished, I want to emit a `value` and want to share that with all current and future subscriptions

```js
    concat(
        from(promise1),
        from(promise2)
    ).pipe(
        switchMap(() => of(value))
    ).share()
```

Is not working, as value gets emitted too early. Who can help?

EDIT 1:

I found a working solution. Are there better ways?

```js
    const initializer = 
        concat(from(promise1), from(promise2))
        .pipe(
            last(),
            switchMap(() => of(value)),
            shareReplay(1)
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since order is important to you, you can simply chain your calls together using [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap):

```js
const initializer = defer(() => promise1()).pipe(
  switchMap(val1 => promise2()),
  map(val2 => '(value from initializer)'),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

We use [`defer`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/defer) to prevent the promise from executing until there is a subscriber.

`switchMap` will map the incoming emission (*value from promise 1*) to the promise 2.  It will emit the resolved value from promise 2.

If you ever have more promises to add to the chain, you can simply add more `switchMap`:

```js
const initializer = defer(() => promise1()).pipe(
  switchMap(val1 => promise2()),
  switchMap(val2 => promise3()),
  switchMap(val3 => promise4()),
  map(val4 => '(value from initializer)'),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-69729209?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=50) sample.

Answer (score 2):

try `Promise.all`

```
from(Promise.all(p1, p2)).pipe(map(() => value))
```

or just use `forkJoin` instead of concat

Comment: This won't guarantee p1 is executed before p2, will it?

Comment: if p1 and p2 are created before this code then nothing will guarantee that. promises are eagerly "evaluated", not at the moment you subscribe to them.